# Where does macOS really install the SF Pro Text fonts?

Tags: catalina, install, font, library, font-book

I know that it's limited for creative use Apple's proprietary fonts, and required downloading a DMG from Apple's Design Resources and installing so you can use it on your design tools, despite it already being basically installed and being used throughout the macOS system already.

But I wanna ask, where does this fonts really reside when installed? And where you can find it? Including the Emoji font?

It's not on the `/Library/Fonts folder` then where is it really?

Comment: BTW, the emoji font is not part of SF.

Comment: @Tetsujin Then what is the exact name of the Emoji fonts on macOS / iOS / iPadOS? And where can I see it?

Comment: That would be a different question 

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its located at System/Library/Fonts.  There are several versions for different uses. SF-Pro for macs, and iPads, SF Compact for iWatch. And a third one for the terminal called SF-mono

Apple has a very restrictive license for these fonts. It may be a good idea to read it.

Comment: Then why going to the `System/Library/Fonts` or on the Font Book app I still can't see any SF Fonts, only the [New York font](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/) shows up